# Tic-tac-toe vanilla js

Tags: javascript, interview-questions

I'm trying to improve my interview skills so I wrote one of the typical assignments - tic-tac-toe game. The main goals are:

- time limit: 30 minutes - 1h
- use only vanilla js

I'll attach source but I created PR in dedicated repo as I think it'd easier to comment for reviewers.

Repo: https://github.com/makbol/tictactoe/pull/2

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game" class="game"></div>

    <script src="./player.js"></script>
    <script src="./cell.js"></script>
    <script src="./board.js"></script>
    <script src="./game.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

main.js

```
const playerA = new Player({
    sign: 'X',
    name: 'Adrian'
});

const playerB = new Player({
    sign: 'O',
    name: 'Ben'
});

const game = new Game({
    root: document.getElementById('game'),
    size: 3,
    players: [
        playerA, playerB
    ]
});
```

game.js

```
const DEFAULT_SIZE = 3;

class Game {
    constructor({ size = DEFAULT_SIZE, root, players  }) {
        this.state = [];
        this.size = size;
        this.root = root;
        this.board = new Board({
            root: this.root,
            size: this.size,
            updateState: this.updateState.bind(this),
            getCurrentPlayer: this.getCurrentPlayer.bind(this)
        });

        this.maxMoves = this.size * this.size;
        this.numMoves = 0;

        this.players = players

        this.playersQueue = [...this.players];
        this.currentPlayer = null;

        this.setCurrentPlayer();
        this.buildState();
    }

    buildState() {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            this.state.push(new Array(this.size).fill(0));
        }
    }

    updateState({row, column}) {
        this.state[row][column] = this.currentPlayer.sign;
        this.numMoves++;
        this.setCurrentPlayer();
        this.checkWinner();
    }

    setCurrentPlayer() {
        const player = this.playersQueue.shift();
        this.currentPlayer = player
        this.playersQueue.push(player);
    }

    getCurrentPlayer() {
        return this.currentPlayer;
    }

    checkWinner() {
        const winner = this.getResult();

        if(winner) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert('Winner: ' + winner.name);
                this.reset();
            }, 0);
        }

        if (this.numMoves === this.maxMoves) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert('Game end');
                this.reset();
            }, 0);
        }
    }

    getResult() {
        const [ winner ] = this.players.filter(player =>
            this.getRowResult(player) ||
            this.getColumnResult(player) ||
            this.getDiagonalResult(player)
        );

        return winner;
    }

    getRowResult(player) {
        return this.state.filter((row) => {
            return row.join('') === player.sign.repeat(row.length);
        }).length
    }

    getColumnResult(player) {
        return this.state[0].filter((column, index) => {
            return this.getColumn(index) === player.sign.repeat(this.size);
        }).length;
    }

    getDiagonalResult(player) {
        let resultLeft = '';
        let resultRight = '';
        let expected = player.sign.repeat(this.size);

        for(let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            resultLeft += this.state[i][i];
        }

        for(let i = this.size - 1; i === 0; i--) {
            resultRight += this.state[i][i];
        }

        return resultLeft === expected || resultRight === expected;
    }

    getColumn(n) {
        let result = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            result += this.state[i][n];
        }
        return result;
    }

    reset() {
        this.board.clear();
        this.numMoves = 0;
        this.clearState();
    }

    clearState() {
        this.state = [];
        this.buildState();
    }
}
```

board.js

```
class Board {
    constructor({size, root, updateState, getCurrentPlayer}) {
        this.size = size;
        this.cells = [];
        this.root = root;
        this.updateState = updateState;
        this.getCurrentPlayer = getCurrentPlayer

        this.buildBoard();
    }

    buildBoard() {
        const board = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            const row = [];
            for(let j = 0; j < this.size; j++) {
                const cell = new Cell({
                    row: i,
                    column: j,
                    updateState: this.updateState,
                    getCurrentPlayer: this.getCurrentPlayer
                });
                this.cells.push(cell);
                row.push(cell);
            }
            board.push(this.addRowElement(row));
        }

        board.forEach(rows => {
            this.root.appendChild(rows);
        });
    }

    addRowElement(cells) {
        const rowElement = document.createElement('div');
        rowElement.className = 'row';

        cells.forEach((cell) => {
            rowElement.appendChild(cell.element);
        });

        return rowElement;
    }

    clear() {
        this.cells.forEach(cell => cell.clear());
    }
}
```

cell.js

```
class Cell {
    constructor({row, column, updateState, getCurrentPlayer}) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.marked = false;
        this.updateState = updateState;
        this.getCurrentPlayer = getCurrentPlayer;

        this.element = this.getElement();
    }

    onClick() {
        if(this.canClick()) {
            const player = this.getCurrentPlayer();
            this.sign = player.sign;
            this.marked = true;

            this.render();
            this.updateState({
                row: this.row,
                column: this.column
            });
        }
    }

    canClick() {
        return !this.marked;
    }

    clear() {
        this.sign = '';
        this.marked = false;
        this.render();
    }

    getElement() {
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.className = 'cell';
        element.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this));
        return element;
    }

    render() {
        this.element.textContent = this.sign;
    }
}
```

player.js

```
class Player {
    constructor({ sign, name }) {
        this.sign = sign;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My main considerations:

- Passing all the way down to `Cell` method `updateState` seems a bit unfortunate

  - Create general `State` class and reuse it among classes?
  - Events? Not big fan - hard to track changes
- Re-render whole board every time something changes or mutate state of each cell?

My biggest concern is about architecture since it's interview assignment.

Comment: You did all this in under an hour? That's impressive! This looks like an extremely well designed tic tac toe game. I personally would go with cell mutation, a full render would require listeners to be re-attached manually.

Comment: Well part of that and general concept I did on interview. Afterwards I decided to finish that so I think it took around 1 hour primarily bc I needed to consider. If I'd have good concept in mind then writing this would take less then 30 minutes. That's why I'm asking for review. I know that kind of assignments repeats on interviews so I want to have basic concept in mind.

Comment: The perfect way would be to write some simple diffing algo but I think there's no time for that on interview (and I don't know how ;)). For full render there's no need to reattach listeners bc they are attached while new instance of 'Cell' is initiated (full render would require to all initiate Cells again). For that case both approaches  are fine but imagine if there would be board with 10^6 cells.

Comment: Yes interesting. I will have to try this exercise for myself sometime.